# Segfault on clicking on QFrame

Tags: c++, qt

This topic might be little lengthy since I have to explain the premise before procceding with the probleme at hand.Firstly my main goal is to have this application in which the user is capable of drag-n-dropping commands from a toolbar in order to form workflows which are send and executed on a remote server.Currently i am working on the client part in qt and it is driving me nuts.

This is my code:

```
draglabel.h

  #ifndef DRAGLABEL_H
  #define DRAGLABEL_H

  #include <QLabel>

  class QDragEnterEvent;
  class QDragMoveEvent;
  class QFrame;

  class DragLabel : public QLabel
  {
  public:
      DragLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent);
      QString labelText() const;

  private:
      QString m_labelText;
  };

  #endif // DRAGLABEL_H
```

```
draglabel.c

 #include "draglabel.h"

 #include <QtWidgets>

 DragLabel::DragLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
     : QLabel(parent)
 {
     QFontMetrics metric(font());
     QSize size = metric.size(Qt::TextSingleLine, text);

     QImage image(size.width() + 12, size.height() + 12, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
     image.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));

     QFont font;
     font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::ForceOutline);

     QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, image.height()-1);
     gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::white);
     gradient.setColorAt(0.2, QColor(200, 200, 255));
     gradient.setColorAt(0.8, QColor(200, 200, 255));
     gradient.setColorAt(1.0, QColor(127, 127, 200));

     QPainter painter;
     painter.begin(&image);
     painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
     painter.setBrush(gradient);
     painter.drawRoundedRect(QRectF(0.5, 0.5, image.width()-1, image.height()-1),
                             25, 25, Qt::RelativeSize);

     painter.setFont(font);
     painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
     painter.drawText(QRect(QPoint(6, 6), size), Qt::AlignCenter, text);
     painter.end();

     setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
     m_labelText = text;
 }

 QString DragLabel::labelText() const
 {
     return m_labelText;
 }
```

```
dragwidget.h
  #ifndef DRAGWIDGET_H
  #define DRAGWIDGET_H

  #include <QWidget>
  #include <QFrame>
  #include <vector>
  #include <set>
  #include "draglabel.h"
  using namespace std;

  class QDragEnterEvent;
  class QDropEvent;

  class DragWidget : public QFrame
  {
  public:
      DragWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
      void setMode(int desiredMode);
      void changePairingMode();
      void showAvailableCommands();
      void initDrawingLayout();
      vector<tuple<QString,QString>> actCommands;
      vector<tuple<QString,QString>> execCommands;
      vector<pair<int,int>>waitingForPair;
      int pairingMode=0;
      QFrame*drawingCon;

  private:
    int widgetMode=1;

  protected:
      void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
      void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
      void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
      void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  };

  #endif // DRAGWIDGET_H
```

```
dragwidget.cpp
#include "draglabel.h"
#include "dragwidget.h"
#include "arrowhead.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QColor>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

static inline QString dndProcMimeType() { return QStringLiteral("application/x-fridgemagnet"); }

DragWidget::DragWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QFrame(parent)
{
    drawingCon=new QFrame(this);
    QPalette newPalette = palette();
    newPalette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::white);
    setPalette(newPalette);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Drag-and-Drop"));
    setMinimumSize(300,300);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::StyledPanel);
    drawingCon->setPalette(newPalette);
    drawingCon->setWindowTitle(tr("Drag-and-Drop"));
    drawingCon->setMinimumSize(350,350);
    drawingCon->setAcceptDrops(false);
    drawingCon->show();
}

void DragWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat(dndProcMimeType())) {
        if (children().contains(event->source())) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else if (event->mimeData()->hasText()) {
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void DragWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat(dndProcMimeType())) {
        if (children().contains(event->source())) {
            if(widgetMode==1)
            {
                event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
                event->accept();
            }
            else {
                event->ignore();
            }
        } else {
            if(widgetMode==1)
            {
                event->acceptProposedAction();
            }
            else
            {
                if(widgetMode==1)
                {
                    event->accept();
                }
                else {
                    event->ignore();
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (event->mimeData()->hasText()) {
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void DragWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat(dndProcMimeType())) {
        const QMimeData *mime = event->mimeData();
        QByteArray itemData = mime->data(dndProcMimeType());
        QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QString text;
        QPoint offset;
        dataStream >> text >> offset;
        DragLabel *newLabel = new DragLabel(text, this);
        newLabel->move(event->pos() - offset);
        newLabel->show();
        newLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        } else {
            tuple<QString,QString> addTest;
            addTest=make_tuple(text,"");
            actCommands.push_back(make_tuple(text,""));
            for(auto it:actCommands)
                qDebug()<<get<0>(it)<<" "<<get<1>(it);
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else {if (event->mimeData()->hasText()) {
        if(widgetMode==1)
        {
            event->accept();
        }
        else {
            event->ignore();
        }

        event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }

}

void DragWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    DragLabel *child = static_cast<DragLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if(!pairingMode){
    if (!child)
        return;
    QPoint hotSpot = event->pos() - child->pos();
    if(widgetMode==1)
        qDebug()<<child->labelText();
    QByteArray itemData;
    QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    dataStream << child->labelText() << QPoint(hotSpot);

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    mimeData->setData(dndProcMimeType(), itemData);
    mimeData->setText(child->labelText());

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setPixmap(*child->pixmap());
    drag->setHotSpot(hotSpot);

    child->hide();

    if (drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction | Qt::CopyAction, Qt::CopyAction) == Qt::MoveAction)
        child->close();
    else {
        child->show();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(widgetMode==1)
        {
            DragLabel *child = static_cast<DragLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));
            if (!child)
                return;
            qDebug()<<"Facem pair cu:"<<child->labelText();
             waitingForPair.push_back(make_pair(child->x(),child->y()));
            if(waitingForPair.size()==2) {
                ArrowHead *line=new ArrowHead(waitingForPair.at(0).first,waitingForPair.at(0).second,waitingForPair.at(1).first,waitingForPair.at(1).second,drawingCon);
                line->show();
                waitingForPair.erase(waitingForPair.begin(),waitingForPair.begin()+1);
                qDebug()<<"Tragem linie";
            }
        }
}
}

void DragWidget::setMode(int desiredMode)
{
    widgetMode=desiredMode;
}
void DragWidget::showAvailableCommands()
{
    DragLabel*grep=new DragLabel("grep",this);
    grep->move(this->x(),this->y());
    grep->show();
    DragLabel*cat=new DragLabel("cat",this);
    grep->move(this->x()+40,this->y());
    cat->show();
    DragLabel*wc=new DragLabel("wc",this);
    wc->move(this->x()+90,this->y());
    wc->show();

}
void DragWidget::changePairingMode()
{
    if(pairingMode==1)
        pairingMode=0;
    else {
       pairingMode=1;
    }
}
```

```
mainWindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
 #define MAINWINDOW_H

 #include <QMainWindow>
 #include <QPushButton>
 #include <QTextEdit>
 #include "dragwidget.h"

 namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
 }

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
 {
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
 protected:
     virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;
 private slots:
    void handleButton();
    void closeAppButton();
    void pairButton();
 private:
    QPushButton *executeCode;
    QPushButton *pairCommands;
    QPushButton *closeApp;
    QTextEdit *inputUser;
    QTextEdit *outputServer;
    DragWidget * commandLayout=new DragWidget();
    DragWidget * availableLayout=new DragWidget();
 };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```
mainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "draglabel.h"
#include "dragwidget.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    executeCode=new QPushButton("Execute");
    closeApp=new QPushButton("Close");
    pairCommands=new QPushButton("Pair");
    connect(closeApp, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (closeAppButton()));
    connect(pairCommands, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (pairButton()));
    void pairButton();
    QHBoxLayout * horizontalLayout=new QHBoxLayout();
    commandLayout->setMode(1);
    availableLayout->setMode(2);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(commandLayout);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(availableLayout);
    availableLayout->showAvailableCommands();
    QVBoxLayout*inputBoxes=new QVBoxLayout();
    inputUser=new QTextEdit();
    outputServer=new QTextEdit();
    inputBoxes->addWidget(inputUser);
    inputBoxes->addWidget(outputServer);
    horizontalLayout->addLayout(inputBoxes);
    QVBoxLayout*withButtons=new QVBoxLayout();
    withButtons->addLayout(horizontalLayout);
    withButtons->addWidget(pairCommands);
    withButtons->addWidget(executeCode);
    withButtons->addWidget(closeApp);
    withButtons->addWidget(new QFrame());
    setCentralWidget(new QWidget);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(withButtons);
}

void MainWindow::handleButton()
{

}
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();
}
void MainWindow::closeAppButton()
{
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void MainWindow::pairButton()
{
    commandLayout->changePairingMode();
    qDebug()<<commandLayout->pairingMode;
}
```

Note:It might seem idiotic but i have the same class for the "toolbar",from where you're supposed to drag commands and also for part where you are supposed to drag commands and pair them.

This is mostly modified code of the fridge-magnets example on the qt website.
The problem that is giving headaches is drawing lines between dragwidget, I have tried drawing everything in the same QFrame but that proved to be disastrous since the whole pixelMap of the instance dragWidget is overwritten at every draw.The solution with which i came up is to overlay a supplimentary QFrame over my dragWidget in order to draw lines there and everyone to be happy,but as always misfortune strikes at every step.When i am trying to click on the command widget everything's fine but clicking on anything other than a DragLabel results in a segfault due to clicking on the QFrame due to childAt() returning the address of the QFrame overlayed on the first instance of dragWdiget();

My main question is: How can i overcome this obstacle

Answer (score 0):

You should use `qobject_cast` instead of `static_cast`.

Add Q_OBJECT macro in each class declaration:

```
class DragLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
  //... class declaration ...
}

class DragWidget  : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
  //... class declaration ...
}
```

Then use `qobject_cast` instead of `static_cast` for `childAt()`, for example :

```
DragLabel *child = qobject_cast<DragLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));

if(!child){
....
}
```